# icon's name, icon's type or icon's tag?

Tags: html

The icon in red square doesn't show up correctly, I am trying to analyzing it.

[image]

I guess it is the same one shown in page tab

[image]

What keywords should I do when searching in its HTML?

[image]

Comment: Try looking for `<i>` element.

Comment: @RobMoll Thank you. I uploaded a new screenshot, the last one, am I searching in the right way?

Comment: I'm sorry. My comment was confusing. What you are seeing is the `<i>` tag being used to italicize text. I meant like this: `<i class="fas fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></i>` for example. Maybe search for "<i" only.

Comment: @RobMoll Thank you. I uploaded a new screenshot, the last one, the first hit is the banner img, am I searching in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Usually images (whether it be 'jpg', 'svg', 'ico', etc) can be found in the `<img>` HTML tags.

Try searching `<img` in the console. You should be able to find your icon.

Comment: Thank you. I went through all 12 of them, none is the guy. Would you please help to [check it](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stiff)?

Comment: Just to clarify: where is that icon not showing? In the browser's tab (at the top)? Or on the actual website?

Comment: Actually it is the icon of items in bookmarks bar, I guess it is the same one as in the browser's tab (at the top)

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks. Yes, the icon of a website found in a browser's tab is also usually the same as the icon found in your bookmarks list (or for Chrome it is as far as I know).  

Maybe try removing that website from your bookmarks and adding it again.  Or clearing your browser's cache.
 
(I believe https://www.hmhco.com/shop/books/assets/product/9780547041018.gif would be the location/icon image that you are looking for.?)

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. You'r so cool! How did you find it? I now know it is a <meta> tag in <head>. When I don't the answer, how could you do that?

Comment: Ok, brilliant! Thanks man.. it's much appreciated! As I mentioned earlier, the icon of a website found in a browser's tab/the bookmark icon, usually has the '.ico' extension, thus 'animage.ico', so one could just search for '.ico' when inspecting a web page and it should give you the address of the image/icon.  And you're right, 99% of the time, the icon can be found in the <meta> tags in the <head> segment of a web page.